# 404 Error in controller action methods after deploying to remote server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

.JS File

```
$("#drpdwn").change(function ()
{
    var filter1 = document.getElementById("drpdwn").value;
    window.location = '/Controller/GetByFilter?filter=' + filter1;
});
```

Actionmethod in controller:

```
public ActionResult GetByFilter(string filter)
{
    var model = obj.GetByFilter(filter);
    return View(model);
}
```

This throws a 404 on server but works as expected on localhost. problem is with URL part and I have no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things when you depoly on remote server, if you deploy at root then it will work i.e. http://www.example.com

But if you added application or virtual directory then you need to use virtual directory too.

```
i.e. window.location = '/[virdir]/Controller/GetByFilter?filter=' + filter1;

So best option will be use absolute url instead of relative to the application.

i.e. window.location = 'http://www.example.com/Controller/GetByFilter?filter=' +filter1;

or window.location = 'http://www.example.com/myapp/Controller/GetByFilter?filter=' +filter1;
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode values like this because this will be deployed in different environments...is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use the web.config for the absolute url, which can be change in for every site without re-publish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")";